# PhoneGap 1.8.1 - super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html") issue

Tags: android, cordova

I'd just download and use latest version of phonegap : v.1.8.1

as usual, I replace the `setContentView(R.layout.main)` line with `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

When I test my "hello world" application, it will always force close. The app can't run properly. But if i change back the line into `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, the app will run properly and there is no problem (for the application). The real problem is, the application not load the index.html because there is no `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");` line.

here is my code :

```
package com.urfinder.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class URFinderActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }
}`
```

Anyone can give me some advise about this?
Thank you :)

Comment: For info, I use min sdk level 8

Comment: Please follow the [Getting Started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) guide and also the [phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart)

Comment: post your full code abt activity

Comment: @NejiHyuga see on my question, i put the full code there..thanks

Comment: many times device may also cause problem, why dont you try on different devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) In your html file, have u put this line in `<head>`?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
```

2) Add this line on top of your activity

```
import org.apache.cordova.*;
```

3) Have you copy `cordova-1.8.1.jar` from your Cordova download earlier into folder `/libs`

4) Have you configure project Build Path?

> Right click on the `/libs` folder and go to **Build Paths/ > Configure
>   Build Path**.... Then, in the Libraries tab, add `cordova-1.8.1.jar` to
>   the project

5) Have you copy `cordova.xml` and `plugins.xml` file from your Cordova download earlier into folder `/res/xml`

This is your check list. Hope it help.

Comment: The PhoneGap getting started guide doesn't mention you have to copy cordova.xml and plugins.xml, so this answer solved my problem!

Comment: @Sandy: Hey i have same above problem which you had, but i could not find where `cordova.xml` and `plugins.xml` , Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Change the class's extend from `Activity` to `DroidGap`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have created the WWW directory in uppercase letters... Try the code shown below.

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/WWW/index.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here as well:

[Phonegap Application in android results in force close when phonegap version is updated from 1.5 to 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309814/phonegap-application-in-android-results-in-force-close-when-phonegap-version-is)

A couple items to check:

1. Did you copy the **xml** folder from the PhoneGap/Cordova archive to
   your **res** folder?
2. Did you copy the Cordova javascript file to your
   **assets/www** folder?

The Hello
Good luck!

Best,

-Auri

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for network error: use relative path(`file:///android_asset/index.html`). make sure there is an underscore between android and asset. Eclipse creates "assets" but instead in relative path we will use android_asset.

I have wasted hours, I was using "android-asset" in the path. Also make sure you copy the xml folder from your downloaded phonegap to the res folder of your project. The xml folder contains config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

// it just beacuse of connection timeout with emulator. add this line before load url.

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

...another thing that can trip you up....the cordova jar and javascript files are created when you create the project, however...on my machine they are EMPTY. I still have to manually copy them into the project folder in the appropriate spot.

We use Sencha Touch, so that is another part of the process where incompatibilities can creep into the project. I load a lot of Javascript from the web and the order seems relevant. I have one project that I am still wringing out, but...you can put a handler in for the WebView onReceivedError event and log the error, which sometimes helps. I also am not averse to placing alert code in the HTML file to find out where the failure occurs. We are using the webkit to serve the HTML locally on the client, too...that is another potential trouble spot.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled hours behind this. 
My Folder structure was:
   assets/www/index.html

And the code in MainActivty.java was:
   super.loadUrl("file:///asset/www/index.html");

The Correct way is:
   super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Its working now. Can someone explain why this "android_" is appended to the folder name?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

...I was following this tutorial:
http://nick.perfectedz.com/2012/10/02/how-to-use-phonegap-with-intellijidea/#comment-286

to make a Hello World with Android IntelliJ Idea3 + Phonegap
and got the same annoying error at "file:///android_asset/www/index.html"

And adding this line to my Manifest.xml file solved the problem like charm:

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
```

Concerning the index.html:
And check if your .js-file is really named like you quoted in the src-tag. 
In this case cordova-1.8.1.js