# Phonegap Application in android results in force close when phonegap version is updated from 1.5 to 1.9

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am doing a phonegap application in android using xhtml 1.0 transitional and javascript . The Application works properly with phonegap version 1.5 but when i changed the  version to 1.9 it showed the following error

**Error** 
Could not find class `'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse` , I searched in google regarding this but found no solution .

When i try to do the same application just by replacing phonegap 1.5 jar to phonegap 1.9 jar file without replacing the js file , the application works , but when i replace both js and jar files to phonegap 1.9 it shows the above error .

**Error** :

```
07-04 11:57:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1296): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10038 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:239)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:195)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager.execute(NetworkManager.java:124)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:211)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:207)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:539)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

07-04 11:57:05.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)...
```

Answer (score 1):

That is some unnecessary logs.It will not affect your code.
However an issue has been filed here by our great [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41679/simon-macdonald) :)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-995

There is some other issue why your application is getting force closed. Please post more logs.

Answer (score 1):

I simply fixed the same error by correcting the path to my cordova-1.9.0.js file within my index.html.

Answer (score 0):

If it was similar to the error I received, then check to make sure you copied the xml folder from the Cordova bundle to the /res folder.  I got the same error as above but it was a red herring.  The real problem that caused the app to force closed was the missing xml folder.