# Application error on AVD with Phonegap hello world app

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am trying to learn Phonegap and made a first app using the tutorials on internet but my  application is crashing showing application error as There was a network error(file://android_asset/www/index.html). I have tried many things but nothing worked for me yet. Please anyone help. Thanks in advance.
 This is my log cat output:

```
07-12 05:33:39.109: D/DroidGap(1395): Resuming the App
07-12 05:33:39.113: D/chromium(1395): Unknown chromium error: -6
07-12 05:33:39.653: D/DroidGap(1395): onMessage(onPageStarted,file://android_asset/www/index.html)
07-12 05:33:39.733: D/Cordova(1395): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1 Description=There was a network error. URL=file://android_asset/www/index.html
07-12 05:33:39.773: D/DroidGap(1395): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-1,"url":"file:\/\/android_asset\/www\/index.html","description":"There was a network error."})
07-12 05:33:40.121: D/DroidGap(1395): onMessage(onPageStarted,file://android_asset/www/index.html)
07-12 05:33:40.273: D/Cordova(1395): onPageFinished(file://android_asset/www/index.html)
07-12 05:33:40.277: D/DroidGap(1395): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
07-12 05:33:40.305: D/DroidGap(1395): onMessage(onPageFinished,file://android_asset/www/index.html)
07-12 05:33:40.309: I/Choreographer(1395): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 05:33:40.365: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1395): Ignore this event
07-12 05:33:41.105: W/EGL_emulation(1395): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-12 05:33:41.417: W/EGL_emulation(1395): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-12 05:33:41.421: I/Choreographer(1395): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 05:33:41.541: D/OpenGLRenderer(1395): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb81cadf0): name, size, mSize = 21, 1048576, 1072788
07-12 05:33:41.985: D/Cordova(1395): onPageFinished(file://android_asset/www/index.html)
07-12 05:33:42.125: D/DroidGap(1395): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
07-12 05:33:42.165: D/DroidGap(1395): onMessage(onPageFinished,file://android_asset/www/index.html)
07-12 05:33:42.265: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1395): Ignore this event
07-12 05:44:42.961: D/dalvikvm(1395): GC_CONCURRENT freed 164K, 5% free 6470K/6791K, paused 23ms+3ms, total 41ms
07-12 05:44:42.993: D/webviewglue(1395): nativeDestroy view: 0xb82b8310
```

and this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<title>AjpdSoft PhoneGap</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript" CharSet="UTF-8" SRC="CORDOVA-2.2.0.JS"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world PhoneGap</h1>
<p>Example of application Android with PhoneGap and Eclipse</p>
< /body>


</HTML>
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

//import org.Apache.cordova.*;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file://android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the app on genymotion.

Comment: hii do you please show me your helloword.java file

Comment: Please Check I have edited the question and added MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Mainfest file changed to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.phonegaphello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.phonegaphello.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and then change in Main activity as:

super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
 super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: I am trying :)... can u tell me what to write in "loadUrlTimeoutValue"as in can i write like this super.setIntegerProperty(3000, 7000);

Comment: no please you can't write, you need to just copy paste

Comment: and this is not solving my problem... but this time there is no chrome error.. but I am still getting this error D/Cordova(1481): onPageFinished(file://android_asset/www/index.html)

Comment: please change this line.. make same name of your cordova file  
    <script type="text/javaScript" CharSet="UTF-8" SRC="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>   capital to samm J to j in javascript

Comment: did that No buddy... still same

Comment: do you please show where CORDOVA-2.2.0.JS and have your add CORDOVA-2.2.0.jar in libs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132852/phonegap-1-8-1-super-loadurlfile-android-asset-www-index-html-issue

Comment: @Adi can you add an image of your folder and the file listing of **android_assed/www** directory in the question? It would help us to give you a better suggestion.

Comment: Thanks frank I have solved it... did changes in my mainfest and then exceeded the load url time to 60000 from 6000